# How to dispatch RTK action on browser back button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I want to dispatch an action that resets the state to initialState when the user clicks the browser back button. This dispatch is used in a useEffect hook. This is what I've got but it doesn't work.

```
function Beginning() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(3);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCount = () => {
    if (count === 1) {
      return setMessage("GO");
    }

    return setCount(count - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if(navigate.action ==='POP'){
      dispatch(restart())
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleCount();
    }, 1000);
    if (message === "GO") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(start());
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count, message, navigate.action]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h3>GET READY...</h3>

        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <h1>{message}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Beginning;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigate` returned from the `useNavigate` hook is a function. Accessing `navigate.action` is just undefined.

I suspect you could use the [`useNavigationType`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation-type) hook.

> ```
> declare function useNavigationType(): NavigationType;
>
> type NavigationType = "POP" | "PUSH" | "REPLACE";
> ```
>
> This hook returns the current type of navigation or how the user came
> to the current page; either via a pop, push, or replace action on the
> history stack.

Example:

```
import { useNavigationType, NavigationType } from 'react-router-dom';

function Beginning() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(3);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  // Use a React ref to cache count state so handleCount
  // doesn't reference stale closure in interval
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  useEffect(() => {
    countRef.current = count;
  }, [count]);

  const navigationType = useNavigationType();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCount = () => {
    if (countRef.current === 1) {
      return setMessage("GO");
    }

    return setCount(count => count - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigationType === NavigationType.POP){
      dispatch(restart());
    }

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleCount();
    }, 1000);

    if (message === "GO") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(start());
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count, message, navigationType]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h3>GET READY...</h3>

        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <h1>{message}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Beginning;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However, the state still doesn't change. I console logged the navigationType and it's indeed 'POP' but for whatever reason the action doesn't seem to be dispatched. I don't think there's anything wrong with the reducer itself since it's a fairly simple one.

Comment: @SüleymanEminbəyli I see. Where, and how, are you checking the `count` state updates? Do you think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that we could inspect live?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get a running codesandbox. It's complaining that I don't have a package.json file in the root folder (which I don't). And I'm not sure how to combine the 2 package.json files, respectively in the client and server folders. Anyhow, it looks like I solved the issue - I put the code you provided (useEffect with actionType) in the Home.js where the back button takes the user.

Comment: @SüleymanEminbəyli Ah yeah, the sandbox would really only need to be a sample of your client code, enough to reproduce the issue. Glad to hear you were able to get issue resolved though. Cheers.